# new Realm versions for Swift 1.2

Tags: realm

I am using the Swift 1.2 branch of realm but that does not seem to be updated with the new Realm releases. it stays on the 0.95.2 release.
Is that intentional or is there something I can do?

Answer (score 2):

The swift-1.2 branch is supposed to be automatically kept up to date with master, but it looks like there was a trivial merge conflict in the podspec a few weeks ago which resulted in the job breaking. It should now be back up to date with 0.96.1.

Comment: Now it updates to version 0.96.1 but I get a huge amount of linker errors when compiling my project. Something seems to have broken..

Comment: Be sure to have Xcode 6 selected (with xcode-select) when running pod install. If you still have issues after doing that, please open an issue on the github repo.